# import scene in xna

Tags: c#, xna

I have a scene that contains mutiple objects. How can i import it in xna and mentain each objects position? right now i export the scene in .fbx and load it in a model like this :

```
 cube.model = contentManager.Load<Model>("cub");
```

but the objects don't retain their position and are all gathered in one point.

I need a method to import all the objects as individual objects but to retain the objects position in the scene?

(i.e. i need to import the scene so that i may manipulate the objects and retain their position in the scene so that i shouldn't reposition all the objects by myself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each object's scene position is in the fbx. The way to get it and implement it is to create a matrix array to hold every object's transform relative to the scene origin, then utilize the appropriate transforms when setting the effect.World for each object during draw time.

```
//class variables
Matrix[] objectTransforms;

//LoadContent section
cube.model = contentManager.Load<Model>("cub");
objectTransforms = new Matrix[cube.model.Bones.Count];
cube.model.CopyAbsoluteTransformsTo(objectTransforms);// the magic is done here

//draw method
foreach(ModelMesh mm in cube.model.Meshes)
{
foreach (BasicEffect bfx in mm.Effects)
{
   bfx.World = objectTransforms[mm.ParentBone.Index] * whateverLocalTransformYouWant;
   //draw here
}
}
```

Without utilizing 'objectTransforms' all objects will be drawn with their local origins located at the world origin, which sounds like what you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

I personally made a level editor for most of the things in my game, but I do have a large scene in blender that links to other models.  That way I can arrange all the level pieces in blender.  When I export each individual piece, it does retain is global position and import correctly in the game.  I would say that the issue resides in your fbx exporter.  There should be an option to preserve location.

What modelling program do you use?  If you use blender, there is an fbx exporter set made specifically for XNA that you should use.